# log4net appender's OnClose() doesn't seem to work

Tags: asynchronous, log4net, shutdown

I've written my own appender to queue requests so that I can send them in another thread, basically an async appender.  My appender creates a worker thread to process the queued requests.  If my appender's worker thread is marked as a background thread, eg. IsBackground = true, then my appender's OnClose() gets called but the process goes down without waiting for that method to finish.  If my appender's worker thread is marked as a foreground thread then my appender's OnClose() never gets called and my application doesn't shutdown.

My guess is that this behavior is due to how log4net detects application shutdown.  Marking my appender's worker thread as a foreground thread makes it such that log4net doesn't detect the application is shutting down (eg. no domain shutdown event or unload, whatever log4net is using to detect).  I can understand that and it seems reasonable.  However, it would seem OnClose() then is of no use as it only gets called when the process is shutting down and that shutdown code is not waiting on my OnClose() to finish.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a correct way to cleanup the resources of a log4net async appender?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Log4net will shutdown on the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload events, and maybe others. Might be worth having a look at https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async

Comment: stuartd - I checked over some of the code in the link you provided.  Unfortunately my guess is that it has the same problem.  They mark their worker thread as a foreground thread.  This causes the OnClose() method not to get called UNLESS the application calls Shutdown on the repository, or at least that's what I read will cause OnClose() to get called.  I'm not in control of the client application and thus cannot rely on that.